# Root calculation by hand (division-like algorithm)

Tags: approximation

I remember from my highschool days a division-like algorithm for calculating square, even cubic roots. I know the continued fraction method, some series and Newton's method. I have checked similar questions in this site with no success.
Do anybody have knowledge of this method?

Comment: You mean this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Digit-by-digit_calculation

Comment: @AymanHourieh: Yes :).